# Foundation CSS menu not showing up for iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, zurb-foundation, mobile-safari

I'm using foundation CSS to make the website mobile responsive. Part of that is the menu that opens on the left side when viewed on any mobile devices. The menu looks great on all platforms **except Safari on iOS device**. Whenever I click on the hamburger icon on my app the off-canvas menu opens up but the content is empty. 
**Foundation core version is 5.4.5**

The following is the HTML code for the menu.

```
<header id="header">
    <nav class="tab-bar header hide-for-large-up" data-options="is_hover: false" data-topbar="" role="navigation">
        <section aria-expanded="false" class="left-small left-off-canvas-toggle">
            <div class="fi-list"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
            <a class="name" href="/" title="My App">My App</a>
        </section>
        <section class="right-small tab-header search" id="search">
            <div class="fi-magnifying-glass"></div>
        </section>
    </nav>
    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
        <ul class="off-canvas-list">
            <li>
                <label>Personal Care</label>
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="/categories/152642-after-shave-reviews-and-ratings">After Shave</a>
                    <a href="/categories/261594-body-wash-cleanser-reviews-and-ratings">Body Wash &amp; Cleanser</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Food</label>
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="/categories/255744-breads-baked-goods-reviews-and-ratings">Breads &amp; Baked Goods</a>
                    <a href="/categories/255757-breakfast-reviews-and-ratings">Breakfast</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Household</label>
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="/categories/167203-air-fresheners-reviews-and-ratings">Air Fresheners</a>
                    <a href="/categories/172613-dishwashing-reviews-and-ratings">Dishwashing</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</header>
```

You can see the **screen capture video** of the behavior here https://youtu.be/NQGnqWBHVuc. 
If you notice carefully, when I close the menu, the menu flashes for a second before it closes. Can someone help me out please? Thanks.

Comment: you could use the remote debugging in safari browser (described f.e. here https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/)

Comment: Please add the version of Foundation you are using to your question

Comment: Added foundation version.